# Removing InnerHTML from a button element

Tags: javascript

I have code that removes the innerHTML from a button element once the button is clicked,  how can I update my code, that when the next button is clicked, it should re-add the innerHTML to the previous button?

Here is my code

```
var drumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");

drumButtons.forEach(function(button, index){
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){  
    var audio = new Audio(audioFiles[index])
    audio.play()
    buttonAnimation(button.classList[0])
    wordChange(button.classList[0])
  })
})

function wordChange(currentButton){
  var changeWord = document.querySelector("." + currentButton);
  changeWord.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  You're already successfully setting `innerHTML` to an empty string.  You can also set it to a string that contains HTML.  Did you try that?

Comment: want to set it back to its default HTML

Comment: There is no "default HTML".  Any time you want to set a variable/property/etc. to a value it previously had, you need to store that value somewhere.  You could store it in another variable, for example.

Comment: Currently, when I click on the button, the wording from the button gets removed, (as expected), what I'm trying to accomplish is when clicking on the next button, the wording should re-appear on the previous button,  (I have a few buttons on my page)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) to accomplish this.

```js
const child = document.getElementById("child")
let orphan;

document.getElementById("rem").addEventListener("click",() => {
  try {
    orphan = document.getElementById("container").removeChild(child);
  }
  catch(e) {
    // no op
  }
});

document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click",() => {
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(orphan);
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 3px dotted chocolate;
  border-radius: 10pt;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <section id="child">
  <h1>some heading</h1>
  <p>some stuff</p>
  <ul>
    <li>a list</li>
  </ul>
  </section>

</div>

<button id="rem">remove child</button>
<button id="back">put the child back</button>
```